# How to check whether Android has internet connection

Tags: java, android, connection

I am developing an Android application.

I want my application to notify me whether Android has internet connection or not. How do I check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Carlo: The simplest way is first to add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission to your application manifest file and write a function like this

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

if the return value is true means internet is working or false means show an alert box :)

Comment: how can I bind this method along with the running application
I mean if during the process the internet suddenly disappear then this method is invoke ?

Comment: @Carlo You need to create a broadcast receiver android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE which will look for connectivity change while your application is running. Look at the answer provided by ihrupin he provided a link for that check that one out :)

Comment: @Carlo: If you feel like my answer is correct can you mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a broadcast receiver for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE intent in your application.

Here is the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Hope, it help you!

Answer (score 1):

//this will check for the wifi, 3G/EDGE and all network availability

```
public boolean networkStatus() {
        boolean status = false;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            String service = context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) BackupSettings.this.context.getSystemService(service);
            connectivity.setNetworkPreference(1);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo[] = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            int cnt = networkInfo.length;
            for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                if (networkInfo[i].isConnected() == true) {
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), " Error at networkStatus() :=" + ee.toString());
        }
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"End  of  networkStatus() fun " + status);
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: don't you think this will return false if netWorkInfo[0] is connected and netWorkInfo[1] is not ?????

Comment: how? networkInfo[i].isConnected() == true only change the status if networkInfo[1].isConnected() == false mean how it will change the status?